# Can I use TFS as source control for rational functional tester scripts with Eclipse IDE

Tags: automated-testing, eclipse, tfs

Is it possible to use TFS source control to manage and store test scripts created with Rational Funtional Tester from Eclipse IDE?

Comment: https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/tfs-for-java-eclipse-devops/)?